# COUNTIFS with nested IF logic

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to count number of cells where both conditions match.

**Condition 1**: Count all cells with the specified date but only return cells where valid entries are present.

**Condition 2**: Count all entries where length of cell is greater than or equal to 10.

Note: Cell length can be string or numbers.

So far I've tried this.

```
COUNTIFS(F5:F14,"="&D5,G5:G14,"<>")
SUMPRODUCT(IF(LEN(G5:G14)>=10,1))
```

[image]

Cell `D5` contains the date which I want to match in range `F5:F14` and `D6` contains valid entries. Range `G5:G14` is where I'm having problems. The correct result should be 4 containing only valid entries
`1007745609` or `1PRI00349523`.
What should I do?

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT((F5:F14=D5)*(LEN(G5:G14)>=10))`

Comment: Using `SUM` & `INDEX` --> `=SUM(INDEX(($D$5=$F$5:$F$14)*(LEN($G$5:$G$14)>=10),,))` but i personally prefer `SUMPRODUCT` since @JvdV Sir has already shared it, so I am sharing another way!

Comment: Thanks @JvdV for the answer.